# MVC Razor ListBoxFor customize/restrict selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `ListBoxFor` and the first item is `All Values`.  I already have the list box set to allow multiple selections.  I would prefer to make it so that if a user selects the `All Values` option they are either asked if they want to clear out all other selections (Use All Values) or keep their current selections (De-select All Values).  I would be ok without the user dialog asking them what to do and just automatically clearing out selections, but that is less preferable.

At first glance it seems that Javascript/jQuery is the best route to go about for this.  I wanted to check to see if anyone knew of built in functionality for `ListBoxFor` that does this.  The other option that I see is building a custom html extension.  Even with this I still only see JS/jQuery being built and auto generated.

Comment: Haven't heard of a razor built in functionality for this.. I suggest use simple javascript to do this

Comment: @krilovich - I agree JS is the easiest way for me to design, I felt it was worth researching to prevent redoing something that might already be done.